# I need a regular expression to grab data from a string, up to a comma

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to grab data from a string, up to a comma.  However, I need to make sure that if the string doesn't have a comma that I still grab the whole string.

Example:  I need what is capitalized in the string below
          "THIS IS THE FIRST PART, this is the second part"
          "THIS IS THE ONLY PART"

Comment: Do you have to use `regex` ? What is the programming language that you use ?

Answer (score 1):

Us the full match (typically `$&`) of `/^[^,]*/` or use group match 1 of `/^([^,]*)/`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this pattern:

```
^.+?(,|$)
```

Of if you really don't want to match the comma:

```
^.+?(?=,|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/2g39yQ/1

Comment: I assume "grab" means capture. This only captures the comma ()which isn't wanted), or EOL. And if "grab" means match, the same problem - matches the comma, not "up to" it.

Comment: it's the full match that's relevant, the capture group is incidental.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
^(.*?)(?=,|$)
```

---

```
^ asserts position at start of a line
.*? matches any character (except for line terminators)
*? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few
   times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
Positive Lookahead (?=,|$)
Assert that the Regex below matches
1st Alternative ,
, matches the character , literally (case sensitive)
2nd Alternative $
$ asserts position at the end of a line
```

If only matching is needed (no capture), remove parentheses around `.*?`, i.e. `^.*?(?=,|$)`.

[Here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/C4PN3W/1).

Comment: @Bill Do you have any comments to the answers you've been given?